# Call global instance of a class object inside its constructor

Tags: c++

It may sound weird as what the title says. Why not just use `this` to call any members than use a global instance of the class itself. But in a project, I just realized I do write such kinds of codes after I finished and reviewed them.

Here is a piece of prefabricated sample codes.

```cpp
// header.h
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();

    void bar();
};

#endif /* HEADER_H */
```

```cpp
// header.cpp
#include "header.h"
#include <iostream>

Foo foo;

Foo::Foo()
{
    foo.bar(); // <= notice here, rather than this->bar() or directly a bar().
}

void Foo::bar()
{
    std::cout << "Hello bar" << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "header.h"

extern Foo foo;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foo.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

```sh
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.cpp header.cpp -o foo
$ ./foo
Hello bar
Hello bar
```

It compiled without any complains and ran well. But I wonder how can this happens. When the program sees a global instance of the class, it's supposed to call the constructor. But insides the constructor the instance is again invoked. Is this a paradox that an instance calls itself before the instance finishes construction process.

And another question, what is available before and after constructor? It seems all member variables and methods have prepared well and been available in advance.

Comment: All instances of undefined behaviour compile without any errors and run. Most of them also appear to work until, suddenly and for no apparent reason, they don't.

Comment: Thing is that during first call to Foo`s constructor, which is for the global instance, this and &foo will coincide, they are the same instance. You can maybe test it using a string passed during construction and declare two instances, the global and another in main() with different strings. Or you can debug and check the addresses.

Comment: @molbdnilo Is it really undefined? Why couldn't one call `foo.bar()` insdide the constructor of `foo`?

Comment: A global at file scope is guaranteed to be constructed before `main()` is called (but, apart from objects like `std::cin`, `std::cout`, etc that are guaranteed to be constructed before other objects) the order of construction of objects in different compilation units is unspecified.   In your case, `foo` is constructed before `main()` is called (and after `std::cout` is constructed) and the call of `foo.bar()` works correctly.   Since `foo` has been constructed when `main()` is called, the call of `foo.bar()` in `main()` also works correctly.

Comment: @Peter Sounds like an answer.

Comment: @DanielLangr - At best, it's a partial answer, since it doesn't address the question about what is "available before and after constructor".

Comment: @Peter The construction order is quite useful. Can you give any references about that?

Comment: @HQW.ang -  Essentially, the standard.  The specification (and wording) have evolved with versions of the standard.  For example, in C++98, look at Section 3.6.2 "Initialization of non-local objects".  In C++17, look at sections 6.6.2 "Static Initialization" and 6.6.3 "Dynamic initialization of non-local variables".   [In C++17, a variable is actually guaranteed to be initialised before it is first odr-used, which doesn't necessarily mean before `main()` is called, but does mean before its first usage].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the standart (n4659 15.7 [class.cdtor] §3)explicitely allows that

> member functions, including virtual functions (13.3), can be called during construction or destruction

Apparently, this code uses the object `foo` in its constructor before that object is fully constructed which should be UB. But as the shown code only uses that object, it will be the first `Foo` ever constructed. At the moment when its constructor is called, `foo` **is** `this` and calling `bar` on it is legal.

But if the application contains any other `Foo` object of static or thread storage duration in a different translation unit, or in the same translation unit but before `foo`, then the program will invoke UB:

```
Foo bar;             // initialization of bar invokes UB
extern Foo foo;
```

Comment: The actually undefined behavior described at the last paragraph is still obscure to me. I try to come about a conclusion based on yours and the unspecified order of construction from @Peter 's comment. Let's say there exists two global objects `foo` and `bar`. If `foo` is the first `Foo` class to be constructed, everything is supposed to be fine. But if `bar` is the first, it calls yet unconstructed `foo` in it constructor, surely resulting in UB. Since the order is undetermined, the overall is UB. Am I right?

Comment: @HQW.ang The standard mandates that dynamic intialization of non local variable *within is single translation unit* is ordered according to the order of the definitions of the variables. So, if `foo` is defined before `bar` in the same translation unit (cpp source file) then behaviour is defined (ref: [basic.start.dynamic] 6.6.3 in n4659).